# Differences beetween past perfect continuous and past continuous

Tags: past-tense

I would like to know the difference between *past perfect continuous* and *past continuous* in these examples:

1. We were playing tennis when it started raining.
2. We had been playing tennis when it started raining.

Comment: I think the question is general reference.

Comment: [An article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_perfect_continuous) at wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

The first means that at the instant it started raining, you were playing tennis. The second means that at the time it started raining, you were already playing tennis for some indefinite period of time.